# What do you do if MemTest86+ finds an error?

Tags: memory, bsod

I've built two similar Hyper-V servers. One is OK but other Windows Hyper-V Core fails in 1~4 days (BSODs with different reasons).

The only different parts are CPU & RAM. Now I'm testing the failed server with MemTest86+ and got an error; `Test:8 Pass: 0 ...etc Count: 1`

Is this error fatal? There are 4 modules of 4GB RAMs without ECC.

Comment: Looks pretty fatal to me. Try removing one DIMM at a time and re-running memtest. You may be lucky and have only one failed DIMM.

Comment: From your description, it is unclear if you have even run a complete test cycle yet (this takes hours sometimes). If there are not bright red parts on the screen, it hasn't found an error yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask what you do? You replace the RAM.

Still got the error? Make sure you're within specs (don't use cheap-ass RAM. Sometimes, manufacturers impose certain requirements on their OEM parts. Make sure the RAM is made for that particular machine. A prominent example is Apple, putting cheap ram in those, even when matching the OEM clocks/timings guarantees a BSOD, even when it's from the OEM itself. Get a certified one from the OEM, it works).

Answer (score 3):

You call the company that sold you the box and ask for warranty. They should replace the RAM.